# Is there a way to dynamically customize the Salesforce Outbound message endpoint

Tags: soap, salesforce

I have a workflow rule that fires up an outbound message when a custom object is created. I create a managed package which included the outbound message, when I install the package on another Salesforce org, the endpoint of that outbound message is locked. I get this message:

> This Workflow Outbound Message is managed, meaning that you may only edit certain attributes. 
>   
> Why?   This Workflow Outbound Message is part of an upgradeable package installed from the AppExchange.
>   
> What Can I Edit?   For managed Workflow Outbound Message, the following items are editable:
>   
> User to send as
>   
> To simplify the upgrade process, all other attributes are locked.

So the question is, does that possible to make the outbound message to read a value(like Custom Settings) as its endpoint, so in the future after install the package, the endpoint is still editable.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to want to use standard callouts which give you a lot more fine grained control.  Hopefully the other endpoint can be REST based, build soap xml from scratch is a bear

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no it is not, the messages include an orgId if you need to dispatch to different places for different customers.